# Showing custom messages to players joining my server

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I have seen many times when joining a server, a message is shown to me like this:

> **console**: Welcome `<user name>`, say hi. Please visit abc.com

How can I do the same thing for my server?

It should be automatically done by the server.

Comment: Couldn't you just ask the server admins that are running those servers what they're using?

Comment: @JeffMercado looks like they(admins) are rude and donn't want to share that :)